# Why is map function doesn't finish it's execution

Tags: node.js, mongoose, map-function

Hi I am building a server with node js, as a part of my project I use MongoDB with mongoose middle-ware , I have a schema called `blogSchema`. I want to get a list of all the blogs in the DB and then foreach blog i'll add an element called `authorized` that tell the user weather he is authorized to see this blog.
this is the request

```
let Blogs = require('../model/index')('Blogs'); // here is the db

router.get('/list',async function (req,res) {
    let blogList = await Blogs.REQUEST();
    let temp = await blogList.map(async function (blog) {
       blog.authorized = await Blogs.IsUserInBlog(req.user.email, blog.name);
       console.log(blog);
       return blog;
    });

    res.json(blogList);
});
```

and here are the function of the schema

```
blogSchema.statics.IsUserInBlog = async function(user,blogname) {
    let isUser = await this.findOne( { name:blogname, users: { $in : [user]} }).count();
    return isUser != 0;
};

blogSchema.statics.REQUEST = async function(cb) {
        let u = await this.find({});
        return u;
    };
```

however , every time I try to request this list when I get to the function  `IsUserInBlog` the code is thrown to the end of the router.post method (to the line `res.json(blogList)` and the list of blogs doesn't change their `authorized` value.
is this because of the async? how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you map on the blogList, you created an async map function, which is ok.

Map function iterates on each of the elements in the array, and in the end return an array.

I think the solution should be to return temp instead of blogList.

So instead of this line:

```
res.json(blogList);
```

You should write:

```
res.json(temp);
```

Edit:

You should use Promise.map as follow:

```
router.get('/list',async function (req,res) {
    let blogList = await Blogs.REQUEST();
    let temp = await Promise.map(blogList, async function (blog) {
        blog.authorized = await Blogs.IsUserInBlog(req.user.email, blog.name);
        console.log(blog);
        return blog;
    });

    res.json(temp);
});
```

Comment: nope, temp return a promise, Iv'e also tried to put await the value true instead of Blogs.IsUserInBlog(req.user.email, blog.name); and it did work,which lead me to believe that there is a problem with using this function in map

Comment: You are right, when you have an array of items, and you would like to iterate on each of them with a promise, you need to use promise.map, i Edited my answer, please recheck :)

Comment: Personally I found another way but the same idea, I used await Promise.all(temp)